# help me create this random number

Tags: c

I am trying to generate a random number with rand as follows:

```
return a + ( rand( ) % n );
```

> Where a is the shifting value (i.e., the first number in the desired range of consecutive integers) And n is the scaling factor (i.e,. the width of the desired range of consecutive integers).
>
> -- C How to program 6th Edition - Deitel

I write it as:

```
return 1 + ( rand( ) % 1000 );
```

and it works, but when I write the code as follows:

```
return 1000 + ( rand( ) % 1112 );
```

I end up getting absurdly large numbers, for example 1756 and 1877. Those were the last two outputs that occurred.

I am returning the value as a integer number to a function call within a printf statement but I am doing the same with the working statement, so I do not think it the way I am calling the function.

What am I doing wrong...?

Comment: Using `rand() % x` is almost always slightly biassed towards the lower numbers in the range (because if `(RAND_MAX + 1)` is not an exact multiple of `x`, there are more values where `rand() % x == 0` than where `rand() % x == x - 1`).  For proper uniformity, you should discard any value from `rand()` greater than or equal to `((RAND_MAX+1) / x) * x`, getting a fresh value from `rand()` each time the value is too large.  If you don't care about the non-uniformity, such refinement isn't necessary; just be aware of the approximation you're making.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Better still, just don't use `rand` and user a proper PRNG ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not doing anything wrong. What is wrong is your expectations.

a is the lowest possible possible number that it can generate, but the highest it can generate is not n... n is the range size, so the highest number it can generate is a+n. It is important not just to copy the algorithm and code, but understand why it works. Let's take a look:

```
return 1000 + ( rand( ) % 1112 );
```

What is the range of rand()? Any number between 0 and RAND_MAX (which is a very large number.

What is the range of ( rand() % 1112)? First, look up the modulo operation. What are the possible remainders when you divide positive integers by 1112? It could be 0 (for example, 0/1112), or as high as 1111 1111/1112 has a remainder of 1111) but after that it loops back (1112/1112 has remainder 0, 1113/1112 has a remainder of 1, and so on).

Now, what is the range of 1000 + (any number from 0 to 1111)?

Comment: I got this to work with `1000 + ( rand( ) % 112 );` but I dont get it I never get a number like 7 if I use `1 + ( rand( ) % 6 );`, thank you for the help though.

Comment: Well... `(rand() % 6)` will give you a number between 0 and 5. Since `1 + 0 = 1` and `1 + 5 = 6` of course you will *never* get 7 from `1 + (rand() % 6)` -- something would *very* wrong if you did. Do you know what the **modulo** operation means? If not, you may want to start [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation).